# How to Copy same file from Multiple Source location using Powershell until it copied

Tags: powershell

I am looking to copy a same file from multiple locations until it copied successfully , file should keep changing the source location one to other and stop once it copied . I have powershell for sinlge location.

I am trying to add more locations here if one location got access denied issues it try with other source location until it copied successfully

I am also using below but no success

```
$Source = C:\arun
$Source2 = C:\rana
$Source3 =  C:\pihu
$Destination = "C:\intunesccmclient"

Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse | ForEach {
    $ModifiedDestination = $($_.FullName).Replace("$Source,$source2,$source3","$Destination")
    If ((Test-Path $ModifiedDestination) -eq $False) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $ModifiedDestination
        }
    }
```

What i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: At first glance, your code wants to copy the file when `Test-Path $ModifiedDestination` returns `$false` (meaning that path does not exist..). Also, what file are you looking for? `Get-ChildItem` without parameter `-File` is also returning directories

Comment: I want to  copy one exe file from  multiple locations , I am choosing multiple source because there will be access denied across multiple domains sources

Comment: We haven't heard from you... If you feel my answer solved your problem, please read the [tour] where you can see how to mark a question 'done'

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I gather this is what you are looking for:

```
# array of source paths to search in. Use UNC paths for remote computers (\\server\share\path)
$Source       = 'C:\arun', 'C:\rana', 'C:\pihu'
$Destination  = 'C:\intunesccmclient'
$FileToSearch = 'TheExeFile.exe'                 # the file to search. Name only

# search in all source paths for the file and loop over the results
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter $FileToSearch -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $_ | Copy-Item $Destination -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Successfully copied '$($_.FullName)'"
        return   # exit the loop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Copy failed: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```